# Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key in React Mobx Component

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am getting this error in my  MobX React component:

```
Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `1:$8`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.
```

This error message not showing if I load this route for first time.

Here is my entire component:

```
@observer
export default class Posts extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.route.posts.getPosts();
    }

    hiren() {
        var bunny = [];
        (this.props.route.posts.posts).map(function (data) {
            bunny.push(
                <div className="post-preview" key={ data.id }>
                    <Link to={'/dashboard/posts/' + data.id + '/'}>
                        <h2 className="post-title">
                            {data.title}
                        </h2>
                    </Link>
                    <p className="post-meta">Posted on {data.date}</p>
                </div>
            )
        });
        return (
            <div> {bunny} </div>
        );
    }

    render() {

        if(this.props.route.posts.loaded){
            return (
                <div className="posts">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

                                {this.hiren()}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            )
        }
        return (

            <div>
                <h3>{this.props.route.posts.loadingText} </h3>
            </div>
        )

    }
}
```

and here is my mobx store:

```
export class Diary {
    @observable loaded = false;
    @observable searching = false;
    @observable posts = [];
    @observable post = {} ;
    @observable loadingText = 'Loading from remote server....';
    @observable pageId = 0;

    @action getPosts() {
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: '/api/diary/',
            headers: {'Authorization': "JWT " + sessionStorage.getItem('token')}
        }).then(action('response action', (response) => {
            this.loadingText = 'Decrypting data...';
            (response.data).map(function (post) {
                let key = forge.pkcs5.pbkdf2(sessionStorage.getItem('key'),
                    forge.util.hexToBytes(post['salt']), 100, 16);
                let hiren = {};
                hiren['id'] = post['id'];
                hiren['title'] = Crypt.decrypt(post['title'], key, post['iv']);
                hiren['content'] = Crypt.decrypt(post['content'], key, post['iv']);
                hiren['tag'] = post['tag'];
                hiren['date'] = moment.utc(post['date']).local().format("dddd, DD MMMM YYYY hh:mm:ss A");
                this.posts.push(hiren);
            }.bind(this));
            this.loaded = true;
        })).catch(function(err) {
            console.error(err);
            sweetAlert("Oops!", err.statusText, "error");
        });
    }
```

I want to get fresh copy of data after component mounting.May be that's why I am getting this error. Is there any better approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error that u r getting used to come, when you assign same key to many element, unique key is required for dynamically created elements.

[From Facebook React Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity. When you don't have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item index as a key. Keys used within arrays should be unique among their siblings. However they don't need to be globally unique. We can use the same keys when we produce two different arrays.

One way of solving this problem is, use the index of item in array, that key will always be unique. Try this:

```
hiren() {
    //var bunny = [];
    return this.props.route.posts.posts.map((data, index) => {
        return(
            <div className="post-preview" key={ index }>
                <Link to={'/dashboard/posts/' + data.id + '/'}>
                    <h2 className="post-title">
                        {data.title}
                    </h2>
                </Link>
                <p className="post-meta">Posted on {data.date}</p>
            </div>
        )
    });
    //return (
    //    <div> {bunny} </div>
    //);
}
```

Comment: Now I got new problem, If I use  `index`  its rendering duplicate data.

Comment: that is not happening because of index, you have duplicate data thats why u were facing issue for ids. ur data is duplicate or somewhere u r adding something to it, please check the logic.